# VALUE INSERTION ERROR

Tags: java, database

I have a new doubt.I want to create a table named admin in macfast database.The table created successfully but when ever i am inserting value in manual way(using query) its seems an error.my code as follows

```
  public void createTableAdmin() {
    try{

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL_table, USER, PASS);
            stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();

            String sql1 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS admin " +
                    "(id INTEGER not NULL, " +
                    " user_name VARCHAR(255), " + 
                    " password VARCHAR(255), " + 
                    " isAdmin BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', " +  
                    " PRIMARY KEY ( id ))"; 
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql1);

            String insert="INSERT INTO admin(id,user_name,password,isAdmin)VALUES(1,admin,admin,1)";
            stmt.executeUpdate(insert);


        }catch(SQLException se){
                //Handle errors for JDBC
                se.printStackTrace();
        }catch(Exception e){
                //Handle errors for Class.forName
                e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
                //finally block used to close resources
        try{
                if(stmt!=null)
                conn.close();
        }catch(SQLException se){
        }// do nothing
        try{
                if(conn!=null)
                conn.close();
        }catch(SQLException se){
                se.printStackTrace();
        }//end finally try
  }//end try

 }
```

the error is something like

```
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'admin' in 'field list'
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

Comment: DON'T SHOUT IN YOUR TITLE. IT'S ANNOYING. ***I CAN SHOUT LOUDER, AND IT'LL BE MORE ANNOYING.***

Answer (score 3):

You're missing quotes `''` around `VARCHAR` column values.

```
String insert = "INSERT INTO admin (id,user_name,password,isAdmin) " +
                "VALUES (1, 'admin', 'admin', 1)";
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not quoting your strings correctly;

```
String insert=
   "INSERT INTO admin(id,user_name,password,isAdmin)VALUES(1,admin,admin,1)";
```

should be

```
String insert=
   "INSERT INTO admin(id,user_name,password,isAdmin)VALUES(1,'admin','admin',1)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your values need quotes or they're taken as field names.

public void createTableAdmin() {
    try{

```
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL_table, USER, PASS);
        stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();

        String sql1 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS admin " +
                "(id INTEGER not NULL, " +
                " user_name VARCHAR(255), " + 
                " password VARCHAR(255), " + 
                " isAdmin BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', " +  
                " PRIMARY KEY ( id ))"; 
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql1);

        String insert="INSERT INTO admin(id,user_name,password,isAdmin)VALUES(1,'admin','admin',1)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(insert);


    }catch(SQLException se){
            //Handle errors for JDBC
            se.printStackTrace();
    }catch(Exception e){
            //Handle errors for Class.forName
            e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
            //finally block used to close resources
    try{
            if(stmt!=null)
            conn.close();
    }catch(SQLException se){
    }// do nothing
    try{
            if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
    }catch(SQLException se){
            se.printStackTrace();
    }//end finally try
```

}//end try

}